# Usage of an asset file for Google Flutter will not appear in one method and works with an error in another?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, assets, flutter, intellij-14

AssetImage() finds the image, but doesn't load it. Image.asset() works, but my package explorer displays an error without specifying the location (removes itself when Image.asset() removed)?

The container object does not have an error in my package explorer, but does not load the image. The Image.asset() shows me that there is an error in the .dart file, yet everything runs as intended. Everything is declared in the pubspec file.  [(Explorer Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uov4Z.png)  [(Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APGH0.png)

```
   new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage(
                    "assets/dispense_rx_logo.png",
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),


    new Image.asset(
        'assets/dispense_rx_logo.png',
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
    ),
```

UPDATE:
IMPORT STATEMENTS:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myfluttertest/screens/login/login_screen_presenter.dart';
```

Comment: What error does it throw? Need more info.

Comment: What error does it throw? Need more info.

Comment: @HemanthRaj There is no error in the IDE! There is just a red line under my file name.

Comment: @HemanthRaj update: if I hover over the Image.asset(), it says Element 'Image' from SDK library is implicitly hidden by 'image.dart'. The app works as intended

Comment: Can you update your import statements in the question

Comment: @HemanthRaj updated

Comment: I've answered your question, hope it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that both `dart:ui` and `flutter:material.dart` has `Image` class defined and the error is with respect to the `Image` class in `dart:ui`. Just change `import 'dart:ui';` as `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`

Hope that solves the issue.